# opencart add extrafield to account

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I just created a row in table customer. I have a module that writes information there. It works fine, but I cannot display this field in template here is what I have changed:
catalog/model/account/customer.php

```
$sql = "SELECT *, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname,' ',c.competition_rate,c) AS name, cg.name AS customer_group FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_group cg ON (c.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id) ";
```

catalog/view/template/default/ommon/header.php

```
<?php echo $competition_rate; ?>
```

catalog/controller/common/header.php

```
$this->data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'), $this->customer->getFirstName(),$this->customer->getcompetition_rate(), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', 'SSL'));
```

And I am getting the following

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Customer::getcompetition_rate() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sport\catalog\controller\common\header.php on line 76

What am I missing? Please help! The information of this row is available throu PhpMyadmin

Comment: this getcompetition_rate() function in not there in customer model or controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the core file `system/library/customer.php` and add this field into the `SELECT` part when logging-in and then create a new *getter* method to retrieve this property.

E.g.:

1. add `private $competition_rate;` after `private $address_id;`
2. add `$this->address_id = $customer_query->row['competition_rate'];` after `$this->address_id = $customer_query->row['address_id'];`
3. create new method `public function getCompetitionRate() { return $this->competition_rate; }`

Now You can call `$this->customer->getCompetitionRate()` method in Your header.

Comment: Sorry still doesn't work. Error doesn't appear but info isn't echoing.

Comment: Sorry again. I just called the method in a rong way.